# calculation issues with tables in python. (simple sales tax program)

Tags: python

I'm Having trouble with a program i'm working on in python, most of the program works, but when I try to calculate a total at the end of the program it doesn't actually add a total, its more like it adds two strings and puts them together.

below is the code I have so far.

```
#welcome message
print("hello customer!\n")
print("How much did you spend on your most recent purchase?")
pre_tax = float(input())
STATE_t =0.05
COUNTY_t =0.025

print("\n\nOkay, if you spent $" +str(pre_tax)+ " then you spent a total of:")



print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>1}'.format('Pre Tax:','$', pre_tax))

state_t = (pre_tax * STATE_t)
state_t = "{:.2f}".format(state_t)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>5}'.format('State Tax:','$', state_t))

county_t = (pre_tax * COUNTY_t)
county_t = float(county_t)
county_t= "{:.2f}".format(county_t)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>5}'.format('County Tax:','$', county_t))

total = (county_t+state_t )
#total = float(total)
#total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>1}'.format('Total:','$', total))
```

and here is the output that I get.

```
hello customer!

How much did you spend on your most recent purchase?
100
Okay, if you spent $100.0 then you spent a total of:
Pre Tax:      $100.0
State Tax:    $ 5.00
County Tax:   $ 2.50
Total:        $2.505.00
>
```

Comment: Next time, try to create a minimal reproducible example. You can read about it at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It's _very_ helpful to use a debugger and step through your program so you can see how each statement affects your variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are converting the numeric values `state_t` and `county_t` to string values so that you can print them.  Because of this, the line `total = (county_t+state_t)` is adding two strings together, not two numbers.  Here's your code with fixes to do the right thing (early part of your code not included):

```
state_t = (pre_tax * STATE_t)
state_t_str = "{:.2f}".format(state_t)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>5}'.format('State Tax:','$', state_t_str))

county_t = (pre_tax * COUNTY_t)
county_t = float(county_t)
county_t_str = "{:.2f}".format(county_t)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>5}'.format('County Tax:','$', county_t_str))

total = (pre_tax+county_t+state_t)
total_str = "{:.2f}".format(total)

#total = float(total)
#total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
print('{0:<14}{1:>1}{2:>1}'.format('Total:','$', total_str))
```

As you can see, I create separate values for the formatted string forms of the numbers so that I still have the numeric forms for doing the math later on.  I also add in the original amount to the total, which seems appropriate.

Here's the output for your example after making the code changes:

```
Okay, if you spent $100.0 then you spent a total of:
Pre Tax:      $100.0
State Tax:    $ 5.00
County Tax:   $ 2.50
Total:        $107.50
```

Comment: Thank you that really helped me out, I was really trying out a bunch of different things to try and fix it with no luck. I'm taking an intro to python class and I usually code into an online compiler, so now I have a reason to get a real compiler with debugger